# Biquery cannot bucket ntile window function

Tags: google-bigquery

Query is:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  session_cnt,
  NTILE(8) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY session_cnt DESC) ntile,
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS session_cnt,
  FROM
    [my_ds.my_table]
  WHERE
    event = 'pageview'
    AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), event_date) <= 30
  GROUP BY
    user_id
)
ORDER BY ntile desc, session_cnt desc
```

The ntile value is 1 for all the rows. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub-query returns one row per user_id!
Your outer select tries to bucket all rows partitioned by user_id, but each user_id has ONLY one row, thus only one bucket generated

Comment: How would I use window for `large results` - it states `partition by` is required. Would I then do `partition by 1`?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. I suggest you to open new question with more details on this so we will be able to help in building correct query. Meantime, if you think above answer actually answers your question - you can vote/accept it